# Is $\mathbb R^n$ added by one point diffeomorphic to $S^n$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a closed smooth manifold. If for some point $p$ on $M$ we can find a diffeomorphism between $M-\{p\}$ and $\mathbb R^n$, then is $M$ diffeomorphic to $S^n$(with the standard differential structure)?

Comment: Nice question !

Comment: In other words, is true that if $M-\{ p\}$ is diffeomorphic to $S^n-\{ p\}$ then $M$ is diffeomorphic to $S^n$ for a closed smooth manifold $M$?

Answer (score 2):

No!
For example, take one of the 27 [exotic differential structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere) $X$ on $S^7$ and delete a point $p\in X$ : you will obtain a differentable structure on the  manifold $X\setminus \{p\}$,  homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^7$.
But there is only one differential structure (up to diffeomorphism)  on $\mathbb R^7$ (or for that matter on any $\mathbb R^n$with $n\neq 4$ : a result of Donaldson and Freedman).
So we may take $\mathbb R^7=X\setminus \{p\}$ and adding the point $p$ obtain a manifold $X$ not diffeomorphic to the standard differential manifold $S^7$.